# Find number of weeks from specific date

Tags: mysql

I want to find weeks from a specific date

If date =26-07-2017

I want  week numbers corresponds to the date

Start date = date and end date should be week date

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither tutorial site nor web search replacement. We however can can help solve [certain on-topic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on the subject in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you want number of the week in year.

to do that you need to do something like this:

```
     int weekNumber = 
        actualWeek.get(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR);
```

with that number you can get dates limits of that week:

```
        LocalDate week =    actualWeek.with(ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber);
        this.startDate = week.with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
        this.endDate = startDate.plusDays(6);
```

where startDate and endDate is a predefined kind of LocalDate variables